# Trouble with when to bind buffers to allow for dragging multiple shapes independently in WebGL

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, buffer, webgl

As part of a larger project, I am trying to first ensure that I can use two buffers to allow my program to differentiate between two triangles and let me drag them independently of one another. In my init function I declare the two buffers using

```
vLT1Buff = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vLT1Buff );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(LT1points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

vLT2Buff = gl.createBuffer();
```

Then, in my render function I call functions largeTriangle01() and largeTriangle02(), which perform necessary rotations and translations to the shapes, and SHOULD bind the correct buffer so that I can move the shape independently of the others. However, I noticed that if I use `gl.bindBUffer` before `gl.bufferData` in my largeTriangle02 function, the two triangles are drawn in exactly the same initial position as one another, rather than their correct respective positions.

The only way I have found to even see both drawn correctly is:

```
function largeTriangle01() {
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vLT1Buff );
var r = rotate(theta[LT1], 0, 0, 1);
var instanceMatrix = mult( translate( dx[LT1], dy[LT1], 0 ), r);
var t = mult(modelViewMatrix, instanceMatrix);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t) );
gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, LT1points.length );
}//end largeTriangle01

function largeTriangle02() {
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vLT2Buff );
var r = rotate(theta[LT2], 0, 0, 1);
var instanceMatrix = mult( translate( dx[LT2], dy[LT2], 0 ), r);
var t = mult(modelViewMatrix, instanceMatrix);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t) );
gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, LT2points.length );
}//end largeTriangle02
```

And in this case, I can only detect when my mouse is in large triangle 01, not large triangle 02 for some reason.

In what order should I be binding the buffers and updating the bufferData?

I set `vPosition` as the vertexAttribPointer as follows:

```
    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
```

and my vertex shader uses this information:

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec4 vPosition;
        attribute vec4 vColor;
        varying vec4 fColor;

        uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
        uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

        void main() {
            fColor = vColor;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

One critical part that it looks you're missing is that the correct vertex buffer is bound when you call `vertexAttribPointer()`. This call, beyond setting the number of components, type, etc., also specifies that the data for the attribute is taken from the currently bound buffer.

So you need to add this call to both of your functions, after you bind the buffer. For example the first one will then look like this:

```
function largeTriangle01() {
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vLT1Buff );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );

    var r = rotate(theta[LT1], 0, 0, 1);
    var instanceMatrix = mult( translate( dx[LT1], dy[LT1], 0 ), r);
    var t = mult(modelViewMatrix, instanceMatrix);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t) );

    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, LT1points.length );
}//end largeTriangle01
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never upload the data in each frame (at least not when the data itself is not changing). A lot of the performance gained by buffers comes from the fact, that their data is uploaded once to the GPU memory and is then only used by the GPU.

This means, you should only upload the data in the initialization function (as you already do). In the drawing functions, you should only bind the buffer, update the matrix and draw everything.

Note, that `bufferData` and `drawArrays` always operate on the currently bound buffer. This means that

```
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(LT2points), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW );
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vLT2Buff );
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc,  false, flatten(t) );
gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, LT2points.length );
```

uploads the data to the buffer that is bound when the function is called. (Most probably this is `vLT1Buff` since this one is bound by `largeTriangle01`). For the rest, it is hard to tell why the program behaves as you describe it, since a lot of code is missing here, for example, the `vertexAttribPointer` setup and the shaders.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I made changes above and included my vertex shader/vertexAttribPointer. Does that shed any more light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See Reto Koradis answer.